# How can I show current service state of systemd service?

Tags: systemd

[image]

I have a `systemd` service(test.service),I want to see the info like the picture when I use command of `systemctl status  test.service`. Especially, I want to see this line that[Status: `avahi-daemon 0.6.30 starting up`]. Which my service don't show it now. I'm trying to show the service current state like `starting/start/stop/stopping/restart` by Status:...

How can I make it ?

Looking forward to you help. Thanks!

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: P.S. Ever wonder why avahi still says "starting up?" It's a bug caused by running in a chroot! There's lots of status messages in the source, including "Server startup complete" but when using the secure chroot, none of them can get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be over-estimating how useful this is :).

For "starting/start/stop/stoping/restart", these should be shown by systemd anyway. (E.g. where it says "Active: active (running)"). *So long as you implement some method of start-up completion notification*. Then systemd can show accurate information.

The nice thing is, the service readiness notification is sent using the same function anyway, as the human-readable status message you asked about :).

If you're writing a long-running program, you *might* decide to additionally implement `STOPPING=1` in case the user sends a signal to your process directly, as opposed to through systemd like `systemctl stop test.service`.  I guess this approach is also necessary for `RELOADING=1` if you want systemd to show that state when you use `systemctl reload test.service`.  (For stopping, systemd knows when your program has finished stopping... because it can see your process has exited).

---

In a C program: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html

> STATUS=…
>
> Passes a single-line UTF-8 status string back to the service manager that describes the service state. This is free-form and can be used for various purposes: general state feedback, fsck-like programs could pass completion percentages and failing programs could pass a human-readable error message. Example: "STATUS=Completed 66% of file system check…"

As a command e.g. for shell scripting: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html

> `--status=`
>
> Send a free-form status string for the daemon to the init systemd. This option takes the status string as argument. This is equivalent to systemd-notify STATUS=…. For details about the semantics of this option see sd_notify(3).

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I will try it.And I want to ask another question that can I get the latest log(such as:May 18 12:27:38 omega avahi-daemon[8216]: Service "omega" (/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.) and  show it as status:Service "omega" (/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.

Comment: I read the example from"https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html  " ,at there we just mkfifo /tmp/waldo but don't put status info to the fifo ,it will read nothing all right? How can we put info into fifo?                                                                         
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo /tmp/waldo
systemd-notify --ready --status="Waiting for data…"
while : ; do
        read a < /tmp/waldo
        systemd-notify --status="Processing $a"
        # Do something with $a …
        systemd-notify --status="Waiting for data…"
done

Comment: the fifo isn't for status information. the fifo is how the example daemon accepts requests. what is the problem with it? you can see how it sets `) the status message b) the fact that it is ready, with the first systemd-notify command. I *think* the implication is you can write a request with `echo "this is one line" > /tmp/waldo`, but whether that works or not doesn't really affect the point.

Comment: @user289678 ^^^^