# Why the line of Active: active (running) just show running or dead when I sytemctl status?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to check the state of  `systemd` service(test.service) by `systemctl status test.service`.But why the  line of `Active: active (running)` just show running or dead rather than starting/stopping/running/dead?

Comment: The current state of a service such as starting/started/running/stopping/stopped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does. I guess you're [holding it wrong](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/events/iphone-4-death-grip).

```
$ systemd-run --user --no-block --service=oneshot sleep 10
Running as unit: run-r0b9dce0a8bd649d4a2e91d23fe757937.service
$ systemctl status --user run-r0b9dce0a8bd649d4a2e91d23fe757937.service
● run-r0b9dce0a8bd649d4a2e91d23fe757937.service - /usr/bin/sleep 10
   Loaded: loaded (/run/user/1001/systemd/transient/run-r0b9dce0a8bd649d4a2e91d23fe757937.service; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2018-05-17 10:49:43 BST; 9s ago
 Main PID: 7949 (sleep)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/run-r0b9dce0a8bd649d4a2e91d23fe757937.service
           └─7949 /usr/bin/sleep 10

May 17 10:49:43 alan-laptop systemd[1667]: Starting /usr/bin/sleep 10...
```

Specifically, if you want systemd to be able to tell whether your service is started or starting, your service needs to actually tell it somehow.  systemd supports a few different ways of this.  The answer linked here shows one of them: "[How can I show current service state of systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442286/how-can-i-show-current-service-state-of-systemd-service/442287#442287)", it shows how you can do this when writing a service daemon (long-running process) in either a shell script or in C.

Comment: Yes. it's my misunderstanding.And thanks for your words,I have got it.

Answer (score 0):

The status of your service will be the current status. To see when the service was in fact started, check your journal log:

```
journalctl | grep test.service
```

This will show you when the service was started, and at this stage the status would have been in the activating stage.

Comment: Thanks ! Can I read the log by line in my code ,so that I can do something by it's content.

Comment: Try to format your questions on Stackexchange with a definite problem, and some context to help us find a definite solution, rather than creating a discussion. You can read the log line by line after the fact, but that's another rabbit hole that we can't discuss here.